# Vaadin и InlineDateField. Как отловить событие смены отображаемого месяца/года?

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin

Необходимо для компонента Vaadin InlineDateField http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#DateInline обрабатывать событие смены отображаемого месяца/года, без смены даты (событие valueChange не возникает). У компонента средств для этого не нашёл.
Единственный способ, который приходит в голову - поменять клиентскую реализацию на свою. Как это сделать?

Comment: Как я понял, на этом форуме на такие громадные и сложные вопросы вам вряд ли ответят! Почитайте документацию! А то мне тоже никто на громадные вопросы не отвечает, только минусы ставят и говорят, что только платно ответят!

Comment: Глупости вы говорите. Тут было много сложных вопросов, на которые были даны удовлетворительные ответы. Минусуют обычно действительно глупые вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вспомнил, что задавал здесь вопрос. Ответ нашёл, может, кому-то пригодится.
Как я и думал, решение оказалось простым. Есть расширенный компонент [StyleCalendar](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/stylecalendar).
Он передаёт события, связанные с перерисовкой календаря (смена месяца/года). Так что самому с клиентской реализацией заморачиваться не пришлось.